# Ping(ICMP) multiple destinations parallely Using Boost.asio

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, networking, boost-asio

I have modified ICMP pinging implementation (https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.18.0/src/examples/cpp03/icmp/ping.cpp) to ping multiple destination concurrently instead of sequentially as shown in the example. I tried with std::thread and std::async(along with futures).

But it works as expected only when all the destination are not reachable. Is it not possible to do it concurrently? I had disabled re-pinging on result/timeout in the pinger class

```
const char* ping(const char* destination)
{
   asio::io_context io_context;
   pinger p(io_context, destination);
   io_context.run();
   return p.get();
}
   
 int main()
{
   std::future<const char*> a1 = std::async(std::launch::async, ping, "10.2.7.196");
   std::future<const char*> a2 = std::async(std::launch::async, ping, "10.2.7.19");
   std::cout<<a1.get()<<std::endl;
   std::cout<<a2.get()<<std::endl; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't need `std::async`¹.

But from the little bit of code you show I can can **guess**² that your error is returning raw `char const*`. The chance is considerable that they refer to data inside `pinger` that - obviously - isn't valid anymore when the future is completed (`pinger` would be out of scope).

A typical way for this to happen is if you stored output in a `std::string` member and returned that from `get()` using `.c_str()`.

> A reason why it would "work" for unreachable targets would be if `get()` simply returned a string literal like `return "unreachable"`, which would NOT have the lifetime problem described above.

### Ditching The Crystal Ball

So, imagining a correct way to return results:

**[Live On Wandbox³](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yVRHTF8hk74NHkKi)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
namespace asio = boost::asio;

#include "icmp_header.hpp"
#include "ipv4_header.hpp"

using asio::steady_timer;
using asio::ip::icmp;
namespace chrono = asio::chrono;

class pinger {
  public:
    pinger(asio::io_context& io_context, const char* destination)
            : resolver_(io_context), socket_(io_context, icmp::v4()),
              timer_(io_context), sequence_number_(0), num_replies_(0) {
        destination_ = *resolver_.resolve(icmp::v4(), destination, "").begin();

        start_send();
        start_receive();
    }

    std::string get() { auto r = _output.str(); _output.str(""); return r; }
  private:
    void start_send() {
        std::string body("\"Hello!\" from Asio ping.");

        // Create an ICMP header for an echo request.
        icmp_header echo_request;
        echo_request.type(icmp_header::echo_request);
        echo_request.code(0);
        echo_request.identifier(get_identifier());
        echo_request.sequence_number(++sequence_number_);
        compute_checksum(echo_request, body.begin(), body.end());

        // Encode the request packet.
        asio::streambuf request_buffer;
        std::ostream os(&request_buffer);
        os << echo_request << body;

        // Send the request.
        time_sent_ = steady_timer::clock_type::now();
        socket_.send_to(request_buffer.data(), destination_);

        // Wait up to five seconds for a reply.
        num_replies_ = 0;
        timer_.expires_at(time_sent_ + chrono::seconds(5));
        timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&pinger::handle_timeout, this));
    }

    void handle_timeout() {
        if (num_replies_ == 0)
            _output << "Request timed out";

        //// Requests must be sent no less than one second apart.
        //timer_.expires_at(time_sent_ + chrono::seconds(1));
        //timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&pinger::start_send, this));
    }

    void start_receive() {
        // Discard any data already in the buffer.
        reply_buffer_.consume(reply_buffer_.size());

        // Wait for a reply. We prepare the buffer to receive up to 64KB.
        socket_.async_receive(reply_buffer_.prepare(65536),
                              boost::bind(&pinger::handle_receive, this,
                                          boost::placeholders::_2));
    }

    void handle_receive(std::size_t length) {
        // The actual number of bytes received is committed to the buffer so
        // that we can extract it using a std::istream object.
        reply_buffer_.commit(length);

        // Decode the reply packet.
        std::istream is(&reply_buffer_);
        ipv4_header ipv4_hdr;
        icmp_header icmp_hdr;
        is >> ipv4_hdr >> icmp_hdr;

        // We can receive all ICMP packets received by the host, so we need to
        // filter out only the echo replies that match the our identifier and
        // expected sequence number.
        if (is && icmp_hdr.type() == icmp_header::echo_reply &&
            icmp_hdr.identifier() == get_identifier() &&
            icmp_hdr.sequence_number() == sequence_number_) {
            // If this is the first reply, interrupt the five second timeout.
            if (num_replies_++ == 0)
                timer_.cancel();

            // Print out some information about the reply packet.
            chrono::steady_clock::time_point now = chrono::steady_clock::now();
            chrono::steady_clock::duration elapsed = now - time_sent_;
            _output
                << length - ipv4_hdr.header_length() << " bytes from "
                << ipv4_hdr.source_address()
                << ": icmp_seq=" << icmp_hdr.sequence_number()
                << ", ttl=" << ipv4_hdr.time_to_live() << ", time="
                << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(elapsed).count();
        }

        //start_receive();
    }

    static unsigned short get_identifier() {
#if defined(ASIO_WINDOWS)
        return static_cast<unsigned short>(::GetCurrentProcessId());
#else
        return static_cast<unsigned short>(::getpid());
#endif
    }

    std::ostringstream _output;

    icmp::resolver resolver_;
    icmp::endpoint destination_;
    icmp::socket socket_;
    steady_timer timer_;
    unsigned short sequence_number_;
    chrono::steady_clock::time_point time_sent_;
    asio::streambuf reply_buffer_;
    std::size_t num_replies_;
};

std::string ping1(const char* destination) {
    asio::io_context io_context;
    pinger p(io_context, destination);
    io_context.run();
    return p.get();
}

#include <list>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::list<std::future<std::string> > futures;
    for (char const* arg : std::vector(argv+1, argv+argc)) {
        futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, ping1, arg));
    }

    for (auto& f : futures) {
        std::cout << f.get() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

As you can see I made the list of destinations command line parameters. Therefore, when I run it like:

```
sudo ./sotest 127.0.0.{1..100} |& sort | uniq -c
```

I get this output:

```
  1 32 bytes from 127.0.0.12: icmp_seq=1, ttl=64, time=0
  1 32 bytes from 127.0.0.16: icmp_seq=1, ttl=64, time=0
  7 32 bytes from 127.0.0.44: icmp_seq=1, ttl=64, time=0
  1 32 bytes from 127.0.0.77: icmp_seq=1, ttl=64, time=1
  1 32 bytes from 127.0.0.82: icmp_seq=1, ttl=64, time=1
  1 32 bytes from 127.0.0.9: icmp_seq=1, ttl=64, time=0
 88 Request timed out
```

> I'm not actually sure why so many time out, but the point is correct code now. This code runs and completes UBSan/ASan clean. See below for the fix discovered later, though

### Now, Let's Drop The Future

The futures are likely creating a lot of overhead. As is the fact that you have an `io_service` per ping. Let's do it all on a single one.

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    asio::io_context io_context;

    std::list<pinger> pingers;
    for (char const* arg : std::vector(argv+1, argv+argc)) {
        pingers.emplace_back(io_context, arg);
    }

    io_context.run();

    for (auto& p : pingers) {
        std::cout << p.get() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Note that the synchronization point here is `io_context.run()`, just like before, except now it runs all the pings in one go, on the main thread.

### Correcting Cancellation

So, I noticed now why so many pings were misrepresented as unreachable.

The reason is because `handle_receive` needs to filter out ICMP replies that are not in response to our ping, so if that happens we need to continue `start_receive()` until we get it:

```
void start_receive() {
    // Discard any data already in the buffer.
    reply_buffer_.consume(reply_buffer_.size());

    // Wait for a reply. We prepare the buffer to receive up to 64KB.
    socket_.async_receive(reply_buffer_.prepare(65536),
                          boost::bind(&pinger::handle_receive, this,
                             boost::asio::placeholders::error(),
                             boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred()));
}

void handle_receive(boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length) {
    if (ec) {
        if (ec == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted) {
            _output << "Request timed out";
        } else {
            _output << "error: " << ec.message();
        }
        return;
    }
    // The actual number of bytes received is committed to the buffer so
    // that we can extract it using a std::istream object.
    reply_buffer_.commit(length);

    // Decode the reply packet.
    std::istream is(&reply_buffer_);
    ipv4_header ipv4_hdr;
    icmp_header icmp_hdr;
    is >> ipv4_hdr >> icmp_hdr;

    // We can receive all ICMP packets received by the host, so we need to
    // filter out only the echo replies that match the our identifier and
    // expected sequence number.
    if (is && icmp_hdr.type() == icmp_header::echo_reply &&
        icmp_hdr.identifier() == get_identifier() &&
        icmp_hdr.sequence_number() == sequence_number_) {
        // If this is the first reply, interrupt the five second timeout.
        if (num_replies_++ == 0)
            timer_.cancel();

        // Print out some information about the reply packet.
        chrono::steady_clock::time_point now = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        chrono::steady_clock::duration elapsed = now - time_sent_;
        _output
            << length - ipv4_hdr.header_length() << " bytes from "
            << ipv4_hdr.source_address()
            << ": icmp_seq=" << icmp_hdr.sequence_number()
            << ", ttl=" << ipv4_hdr.time_to_live() << ", time="
            << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(elapsed).count();
    } else start_receive();
}
```

Now, `handle_timeout` can be simplified to:

```
void handle_timeout() {
    if (num_replies_ == 0) {
        socket_.cancel(); // _output is set in response to error_code
    }
}
```

> In fact, we might simplify to remove `num_replies` altogether, but I'll leave this as an exorcism for the reader

### Full Demo

**[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6S3tpEDOCK1bluf3)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
namespace asio = boost::asio;

#include "icmp_header.hpp"
#include "ipv4_header.hpp"

using asio::steady_timer;
using asio::ip::icmp;
namespace chrono = asio::chrono;

class pinger {
  public:
    pinger(asio::io_context& io_context, const char* destination)
            : resolver_(io_context), socket_(io_context, icmp::v4()),
              timer_(io_context), sequence_number_(0), num_replies_(0) {
        destination_ = *resolver_.resolve(icmp::v4(), destination, "").begin();

        start_send();
        start_receive();
    }

    std::string get() { auto r = _output.str(); _output.str(""); return r; }
  private:
    void start_send() {
        std::string body("\"Hello!\" from Asio ping.");

        // Create an ICMP header for an echo request.
        icmp_header echo_request;
        echo_request.type(icmp_header::echo_request);
        echo_request.code(0);
        echo_request.identifier(get_identifier());
        echo_request.sequence_number(++sequence_number_);
        compute_checksum(echo_request, body.begin(), body.end());

        // Encode the request packet.
        asio::streambuf request_buffer;
        std::ostream os(&request_buffer);
        os << echo_request << body;

        // Send the request.
        time_sent_ = steady_timer::clock_type::now();
        socket_.send_to(request_buffer.data(), destination_);

        // Wait up to five seconds for a reply.
        num_replies_ = 0;
        timer_.expires_at(time_sent_ + chrono::seconds(5));
        timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&pinger::handle_timeout, this));
    }

    void handle_timeout() {
        if (num_replies_ == 0) {
            socket_.cancel(); // _output is set in response to error_code
        }
    }

    void start_receive() {
        // Discard any data already in the buffer.
        reply_buffer_.consume(reply_buffer_.size());

        // Wait for a reply. We prepare the buffer to receive up to 64KB.
        socket_.async_receive(reply_buffer_.prepare(65536),
                              boost::bind(&pinger::handle_receive, this,
                                 boost::asio::placeholders::error(),
                                 boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred()));
    }

    void handle_receive(boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length) {
        if (ec) {
            if (ec == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted) {
                _output << "Request timed out";
            } else {
                _output << "error: " << ec.message();
            }
            return;
        }
        // The actual number of bytes received is committed to the buffer so
        // that we can extract it using a std::istream object.
        reply_buffer_.commit(length);

        // Decode the reply packet.
        std::istream is(&reply_buffer_);
        ipv4_header ipv4_hdr;
        icmp_header icmp_hdr;
        is >> ipv4_hdr >> icmp_hdr;

        // We can receive all ICMP packets received by the host, so we need to
        // filter out only the echo replies that match the our identifier and
        // expected sequence number.
        if (is && icmp_hdr.type() == icmp_header::echo_reply &&
            icmp_hdr.identifier() == get_identifier() &&
            icmp_hdr.sequence_number() == sequence_number_) {
            // If this is the first reply, interrupt the five second timeout.
            if (num_replies_++ == 0)
                timer_.cancel();

            // Print out some information about the reply packet.
            chrono::steady_clock::time_point now = chrono::steady_clock::now();
            chrono::steady_clock::duration elapsed = now - time_sent_;
            _output
                << length - ipv4_hdr.header_length() << " bytes from "
                << ipv4_hdr.source_address()
                << ": icmp_seq=" << icmp_hdr.sequence_number()
                << ", ttl=" << ipv4_hdr.time_to_live() << ", time="
                << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(elapsed).count();
        } else start_receive();
    }

    static unsigned short get_identifier() {
#if defined(ASIO_WINDOWS)
        return static_cast<unsigned short>(::GetCurrentProcessId());
#else
        return static_cast<unsigned short>(::getpid());
#endif
    }

    std::ostringstream _output;

    icmp::resolver resolver_;
    icmp::endpoint destination_;
    icmp::socket socket_;
    steady_timer timer_;
    unsigned short sequence_number_;
    chrono::steady_clock::time_point time_sent_;
    asio::streambuf reply_buffer_;
    std::size_t num_replies_;
};

#include <list>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    asio::io_context io_context;

    std::list<pinger> pingers;
    for (char const* arg : std::vector(argv+1, argv+argc)) {
        pingers.emplace_back(io_context, arg);
    }

    io_context.run();

    for (auto& p : pingers) {
        std::cout << p.get() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Now the output of e.g. `time sudo ./sotest 127.0.0.{1..100} 18.0.0.1` is as expected:

```
32 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1, ttl=64, time=8
32 bytes from 127.0.0.2: icmp_seq=1, ttl=64, time=8
32 bytes from 127.0.0.3: icmp_seq=1, ttl=64, time=8
32 bytes from 127.0.0.4: icmp_seq=1, ttl=64, time=8
...
32 bytes from 127.0.0.98: icmp_seq=1, ttl=64, time=0
32 bytes from 127.0.0.99: icmp_seq=1, ttl=64, time=0
32 bytes from 127.0.0.100: icmp_seq=1, ttl=64, time=0
Request timed out
```

---

¹ in fact that is rarely/never the right tool

² using my crystal ball

³ obviously we have no permissions to craft ICMP packets, let alone send them on Wandbox

Comment: TL;DR use C++ types, mind lifetimes, avoid threading. Also, copy/paste from the last listing if you must (because of the many small improvements along the way)

Comment: I tried similar solutions, but it did not work out. Now also it does not work out. Pinging the loopback address followed by 18.0.0.1 works for me. But pinging in this case I get the response kile this (where 2nd one is unreachable).                                                                             
                                                                                                                               sudo ./a.out  10.2.7.194 18.0.0.2
32 bytes from 10.2.7.194: icmp_seq=1, ttl=60, time=27
32 bytes from 10.2.7.194: icmp_seq=1, ttl=60, time=27

Comment: $ sudo ./a.out  10.2.7.194  18.0.0.2 # Does not work fine Why?
32 bytes from 10.2.7.194: icmp_seq=1, ttl=60, time=26
32 bytes from 10.2.7.194: icmp_seq=1, ttl=60, time=26

$ sudo ./a.out  127.0.0.1  18.0.0.2 # Good
32 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1, ttl=64, time=0
Request timed out

$ sudo ./a.out  10.2.4.190  18.0.0.2 #Good Both are unreachable
Request timed out
Request timed out

Comment: I think what's going wrong here is that ICMP is connectionless - like UDP, and you're receiving multiple responses for the same IP. Weirdly it /says/ `from 10.2.7.194: icmp_seq=1` both times. That means you're actually SENDING echo requests twice as well, from the same process. I think you want to show me the exact code. Why not post it on wandbox, like I did?

Comment: I just copy pasted your code and compiled with gcc.. Just changed the placeholders error and bytes_transferred to _1 and _2 in async_receive.  I did not change anything else. Do Ineed to clear anything in handle receive. Is there a conceptual bug in the code. (Like it is allowed to ping one destination at a time from a process)

Comment: Can you ... still show me? [Why did you replace the placeholders?) Something is clearly going on. Are you on linux/windows/mac? Are you _positive_ that you're not running multiple copies of the process? [Like e.g. even in containers].

Comment: i tried in a different system with Ubuntu 20.04, g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0, #define BOOST_LIB_VERSION "1_71" but the problem remains same. I used same file (including headers)as you posted on wandbox. I used `g++ ping.cpp -std=c++17 -lpthread` for compilation(I linked pthread since i got undefind refence to pthread_*). I also tried with clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1. But no difference

Comment: I used different seq number for different destinations. I think the issue is with the way we bind handle_receive.. This function will be called on receiving the reply from any destination.  All messages are filtered out except the first one. But when we recieve the reply from subsequent destinations the handle_receive will not be called at all since it was already called

Comment: That is the issue indeed, but not due to the bind. It's due to nature of ICMP - like UD{P, it's connection less. I had been reading up yesterday, but didn't find the time to actually code up a better example. I do agree that making the sequence number unique might be a good first step. I'm tempted to look at how [fping](https://fping.org/fping.1.html) or similar are implemented in this respect.

Comment: I think the following check is wrong:

if (is && icmp_hdr.type() == icmp_header::echo_reply && icmp_hdr.identifier() == get_identifier() && icmp_hdr.sequence_number() == sequence_number_)

in fact for each pinger the header type is always echo, the identifier is the same and the sequence number starts from 1 for each one. So a pinger can get the reply of another host. This is not working.

Comment: I modified the example by @sehe to have unique sequence_number_:

1) const std::string& instead of const char* as "destination" parameter in the constructor 
2) sequence_number initialized from destination: sequence_number_(std::stoi(destination.substr(destination.find_last_of('.') + 1, destination.size())))
3) avoid increment of sequence_number_ in start_send().

but unfortunately running the pinger several times, the total result is not always the same. I mean that sometimes some hosts are not found. Tried with tcpdump and it seems all icmp packets are sent but someone is not received.

Comment: @gambr looks like you're right. I'd instead make `get_identifier` return something useful, like: https://wandbox.org/permlink/KrbxPlBldKb8R4Im

Comment: On large-scale receiving I think stability can be improved by receiving using a single socket, instead of pinger per destination. Perhaps a more recent answer about UDP receiving can inspire? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+udp